# Which version is compatible with which? Spring and JSTL

Tags: spring, maven, jstl

I am new to Maven. Now, in my POM, I declared I need Spring 3.0.5.RELEASE. After I started my server and tried to access a page, the server threw a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config error.

Now after researching online, I found that I need to include a JSTL dependency like so:

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have faced this question multiple times. How do I know which version of jstl is comptabile with Spring 3.0.5.RELEASE

I know this might be a basic question but it will help everyone

Comment: Spring 3.0.5.RELEASE: why? Why do you start a new project with such an old spring release, that is 7 years old, is EOLed for a long time, thus isn't maintained anymore, and of course relies on a whole bunch of old versions of other libraries, too? Use the latest stable release. If you started a new software company, would you start by buying a 7-year-old computer running Windows 2000?

Comment: @JBNizet: agreed with your comment. Now, how do I find which versions/libraries are compatible with the latest version of Spring?

Comment: You read the documentation (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#view-jsp), the pom (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/4.3.8.RELEASE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try generating a Spring Boot Maven project via http://start.spring.io/ rather then manually setting one up.